# chrome.hid.getDevices() and chrome.usb.getDevices() not returning any results

Tags: macos, usb, google-chrome-app, hid, google-chrome-os

I've run into what appears to be a basic problem with `chrome.hid.getDevices()` and `chrome.usb.getDevices()` not returning results. Positive it's a PEBKAC, not exactly sure where I'm going wrong, hope you guys can help.

I've setup a [minimal example](https://github.com/angrytongan/chromeapp-testing) according to the Chrome developer documentation. `manifest.json` setup with correct permissions to access USB and HID. Experimental API flag set in `chrome://flags`. System information shows full list of attached USB devices.

Tested on Chrome Stable Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.10.5 and Chrome Stable Version 49.0.2623.111 on Chrome OS.

When the sample is run, I see no devices returned from `chrome.hid.getDevices()` or `chrome.usb.getDevices()`. `chrome.usb.getUserSelectedDevices()` does show the USB dialog box; on Mac OS X it is populated correctly, on Chrome OS there are no devices.

Hoping someone can lart me in the right direction. Thanks heaps.

Comment: I think this is currently an open bug, here is the link to keep you updated on the status of the [reported issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584599) and the previous SO question that encountered the same issue on `chrome.usb.getDevices`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few minor issues with the example in your repo. Firstly according to the chrome.usb API documentation you must include `vendorId` and `productId` pairs for each device you want to use under the permissions in the manifest:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#manifest

for example:

```
"permissions": ["usb",
    {
        "usbDevices": [
            {
                "vendorId": 1626,
                "productId": 40961
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can get the IDs using your `chrome.usb.getUserSelectedDevices` example output.

Secondly your `chrome.usb.getDevices()` example is attempting to use `chrome.hid.getDevices()`